# Using .text() to only modify text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use `.text()` to modify text, but not other elements in a select element?

```
var titleTextDiv = $('div#title-text'),
    editTitleDiv = $('div#title-edit'),
    editTitleInput = $('input[name=imageTitle]'),
    editTitleLink = $('a#edit-title'),
    saveTitleLink = $('a#save-title');

editTitleDiv.hide();
editTitleInput.val($.trim(titleTextDiv.text()));

editTitleLink.click(function() {
    titleTextDiv.hide();
    editTitleDiv.fadeIn('fast');
});

saveTitleLink.click(function() {
    editTitleDiv.hide();
    titleTextDiv.text($.trim(editTitleInput.val())).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

**[ jsFIDDLE ]** http://jsfiddle.net/2xMtQ/

At the moment, everything works, except after the title has changed to the new value, it removes the edit/save anchor. Why is this? What can I do differently?

Comment: Add a `<span>` for the text.

Comment: you should filter for text node only.

Comment: BTW, you forgot a small thing... THE HTML!!!

Comment: @gdoron, thanks for that. I didn't want to clutter the question, which is why I linked to the fiddle.

Comment: But made it useless as the jQuery code has no meaning without the HTML. anyway it's super-localized question in it's current format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the target text in a `<span>`, like:

```
<span id="title-target">Dem Bears</span>
```

and modify that span's text instead of the container, like:

```
var titleTextDiv = $('div#title-text'),
    titleTarget = $("#title-target"),
    editTitleDiv = $('div#title-edit'),
    editTitleInput = $('input[name=imageTitle]'),
    editTitleLink = $('a#edit-title'),
    saveTitleLink = $('a#save-title');

editTitleDiv.hide();
editTitleInput.val($.trim(titleTextDiv.text()));

editTitleLink.click(function() {
    titleTextDiv.hide();
    editTitleDiv.fadeIn('fast');
});

saveTitleLink.click(function() {
    editTitleDiv.hide();
    titleTarget.text($.trim(editTitleInput.val()));
    titleTextDiv.fadeIn("fast");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2xMtQ/1/

Also, it's unnecessary to use the tagName when selecting an element by `id`, since jQuery optimizes the selection process for selectors that start with "#". When you use something before "#", jQuery must process the selector more than necessary, and is inefficient. For example, use `$('#title-text')` instead of `$('div#title-text')`.

Looking at the jQuery source code, what `.text("string")` is doing is emptying the elements' contents, then adding a single text node with the string passed in. That's why you're seeing everything inside being replace. The relevant jQuery:

```
this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
```

which, like I said, in short, is emptying the element and appending one text node.

Comment: _"redundant/unnecessary"_ aren't the right words since: _"For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match."_

Comment: @gdoron From that description, "Redundant/Unnecessary" are the perfect words. Why include all extra stuff when jQuery doesn't care and it's **redundant**? All they do is look for `"#"`. Anything before it is basically ignored. The wrong word would be "Incorrect".

Comment: It's not being ignored, that's the problem, it's being tested, wasting CPU cycles, then being ignored, that's the problem.

Comment: @gdoron You are quite right. I was confused by the regex I saw jQuery using internally, and was mistaken by what it was actually doing....I'll just leave it at that. When I tried some samples, I understood. So I'll gladly update my answer. To me, I'd say it's still "unnecessary"...not "redundant" though...but I'll explain what I mean. So thank you for bringing that up, and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing elements removed when using `text` is because that method will "Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text."

This may seem deceiving because when used initially `text` will only return the text of the element, even if there are nested children. However, the setter is a much different story and will overwrite the content in there.

In order to be able to use jQuery's `text` to only modify text in an element you should *localize your text* so that it can be properly targeted for modification.

## A review of jQuery's text.

### jQuery's `text` as a:

#### *Getter*

- Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

#### *Setter*

- Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text

(source: **[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**)

---

Your localized question

## ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2xMtQ/3/)***

You need to restructure your elements a little. Text will replace everything inside of that area so you probably want to go with a span for the text. Here is a modified version as a suggestion:

```
<div id="title-div"><span id="title-text">Dem Bears</span>
```

and then in js

```
var titleTextDiv = $('div#title-div'),
titleText = $('span#title-text'),
editTitleDiv = $('div#title-edit'),
editTitleInput = $('input[name=imageTitle]'),
editTitleLink = $('a#edit-title'),
saveTitleLink = $('a#save-title');

editTitleDiv.hide();
editTitleInput.val($.trim(titleText.text()));

editTitleLink.click(function() {
 titleTextDiv.hide();
 editTitleDiv.fadeIn('fast');
});

saveTitleLink.click(function() {
 editTitleDiv.hide();
 titleText.text($.trim(editTitleInput.val()));
 titleTextDiv.fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to you can change `.text()` to preserve nodes and just replace text

```
$.fn.text = function ( value ) {
    return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
        if(value === undefined){
            return jQuery.text( this );
        }else{
        var childNodes = this.children().detach();
        return this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) ).append(childNodes);
        }
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
}
```

though I would recommend just adding it as an additional function

```
$.fn.textPreserveNodes
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2xMtQ/10/

Comment: Why the downvote? The question was:"How can I use .text() to modify text, but not other elements in a select element?" I believe this answer answers that question

Comment: Foshizzle, I added an edit about using it as an additional function